# SQLAlchemy Connection Error in Dockerized Flask Application

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, flask-sqlalchemy

Greetings I have a `config.py` file with the following code block.

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/dataset_creator'
```

This flask application connects to postgreSQL database on localhost with terminal code `python app.py` and works fine. However, when I dockerize this FLASK application with the following docker commands, I get an error in SQL connection.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgresql
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root

  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  datasetcreator:
    container_name: orion-flask-app
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

The log records of the error I get are as follows:

```
2023-01-23 16:44:02 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return fn()
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 327, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 894, in _checkout
2023-01-23 16:44:02     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 493, in checkout
2023-01-23 16:44:02     rec = pool._do_get()
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
2023-01-23 16:44:02     with util.safe_reraise():
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2023-01-23 16:44:02     compat.raise_(
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2023-01-23 16:44:02     raise exception
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return self._create_connection()
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 388, in __init__
2023-01-23 16:44:02     self.__connect()
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 690, in __connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     with util.safe_reraise():
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2023-01-23 16:44:02     compat.raise_(
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2023-01-23 16:44:02     raise exception
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2023-01-23 16:44:02 psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
2023-01-23 16:44:02 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2023-01-23 16:44:02 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-01-23 16:44:02 could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
2023-01-23 16:44:02 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
2023-01-23 16:44:02 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-01-23 16:44:02 
2023-01-23 16:44:02 
2023-01-23 16:44:02 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2023-01-23 16:44:02 
2023-01-23 16:44:02 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/app/app.py", line 23, in <module>
2023-01-23 16:44:02     create_database(engine.url)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py", line 574, in create_database
2023-01-23 16:44:02     with engine.begin() as connection:
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3143, in begin
2023-01-23 16:44:02     conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:02     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
2023-01-23 16:44:02     else engine.raw_connection()
2023-01-23 16:44:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
2023-01-23 16:44:03     util.raise_(
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2023-01-23 16:44:03     raise exception
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return fn()
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 327, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 894, in _checkout
2023-01-23 16:44:03     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 493, in checkout
2023-01-23 16:44:03     rec = pool._do_get()
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
2023-01-23 16:44:03     with util.safe_reraise():
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2023-01-23 16:44:03     compat.raise_(
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2023-01-23 16:44:03     raise exception
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return self._create_connection()
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 388, in __init__
2023-01-23 16:44:03     self.__connect()
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 690, in __connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     with util.safe_reraise():
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2023-01-23 16:44:03     compat.raise_(
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2023-01-23 16:44:03     raise exception
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2023-01-23 16:44:03   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
2023-01-23 16:44:03     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
2023-01-23 16:44:03 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
2023-01-23 16:44:03 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2023-01-23 16:44:03 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-01-23 16:44:03 could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
2023-01-23 16:44:03 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
2023-01-23 16:44:03 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2023-01-23 16:44:03 
2023-01-23 16:44:03 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

[Latest status of containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUiMY.png)

I will be glad if you help. I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Configure networking links to connect services: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#link-containers

Comment: You need to use the Compose service name `db` as the host name in your connection string; `localhost` from within the Flask container will refer to that same container.  Your Compose setup is fine and you do not need to manually add `networks:` or the obsolete `links:`.